# Selecting rows with specific columns having a null or 'default' value

Tags: mysql

I've got a rather large DB and I need to select the fields where they are null or defaulted.

For example:

```
Table: Table_A
Row #1234
    name,  mname, lname
    [data] [data] [null]
```

I'd need a query to generalize this, so that I can select "lname", where it is NULL, or mname, or none based on its state.

--

I just need to SELECT all "NULL" or "FALSE" fields in a row, and return only those fields which are NULL or FALSE.

Comment: come again? there is no such thing as a null row. You need to explain what you are trying to do a lot better.

Comment: @MikeNakis I meant "fields". I apologize.

Comment: Edited my original post.

Comment: So, what do you expect this query to retrieve if in row #1234 lname is NULL, but in row #1235 name is NULL?

Comment: To return 'name' only. If lname is NULL, and mname is NULL, then it would return both.

Comment: Ok to clarify: you have many tables and you want to return all rows from all tables which has FALSE or NULL in some fields?

Comment: @TalasanNicholson: IMO, you should consider if you really need this functionality. If I were you, I would return the rows then have the app determine how to render the name. For example, if only name was returned, to show it, but if name and lname were returned, show both.

Comment: @Piotrekkr: Yes, that's right.



DigitalPrecision: I'm thinking this is how it will have to be done. I'm trying to avoid a lot of code for such a simple thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 IS NULL or col2 IS NULL or ... or col1 = 'default' or col2 = 'default' ...
```

Comment: OP mentioned that this is a large DB, and although ORs would work, they would result in a painful query.

Comment: sorry if I read `large db` i think database with big amount of data / rows not big number of columns :)

Comment: The data spans over multiple tables; I can JOIN them and do this. Would that eat my performance?

Comment: Large could relate to width of table or number of rows, as far as optimization it doesn't really matter, the ORs have the potential to cause un-needed load on the database.